# How to adjust the position of subfloat?

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment

I want to align the axes in (a) and (b) which I've marked on the picture, like they do in (c) and (d)?

[image]

The main code is below：

```
\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{pre_coherent_a.eps}%
\label{pre:a}}
\hfil
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{pre_coherent_b.eps}%
\label{pre:b}}
\hfil
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{pre_coherent_c.eps}%
\label{pre:c}}
\hfil
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{pre_coherent_d.eps}%
\label{pre:d}}
\caption{Main processing stages of pre-coherent processing.}
\vspace{-10 pt}  % adjust the vertical spacing
\label{fig_sim1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: This makes no sense. (a) and (b) are already vertically aligned on the same baseline in the image.

Comment: You may not understand my intention.@Zarko has solved my question. Also thank you for your attention and answers！

Comment: I see; you're attempting to align vertically the *axes* of the two images.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is possible if you:

- redraw image (a): (re)move all below abscissa or (b): below abscissa add phantom node with $\Delta_{\min}$,
- enclose image (b) in `\raisebox` and lift it for desired amount ...

MWE for the last possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{pre_coherent_a.eps}%
\label{pre:a}}
\hfil
\subfloat[]{\raisebox{1ex}% select appropriate amount
            {\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{pre_coherent_b.eps}}%
\label{pre:b}}


\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{pre_coherent_c.eps}%
\label{pre:c}}
\hfil
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{pre_coherent_d.eps}%
\label{pre:d}}
\caption{Main processing stages of pre-coherent processing.}
\vspace{-10 pt}  % adjust the vertical spacing
\label{fig_sim1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note:* for caption formatting is better to load `caption` package and adequately set up it features as locally  manual change for example vertical space between caption and figure.

Comment: I appreciate a lot for you. Your proposed method perfectly solved  my question. Thank you ！

Comment: @刘兴华, then please upvote and accept my answer (by clicking on upside pen and check mark on the top left side of answer) :)  This is supposed to be instead to say "thank you" ... Happy TeXing!

Comment: It is my first time to ask question! I don't know much about the meaning of some icons in this website...  Perhaps， I have clicked on downside pen  before. Sorry!