# move figure in subfloat (subfig package)

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, subfloats

I would like to align the figures in the picture, I have tried many solutions I found in internet, but nothing worked for me. I am using the subfig package. I have covered the figures because I do not own the rights. The first one was generated with Gnuplot (epslatex terminal), the second one is a simple pdf image.
Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\subfloat[Caratterizzazione IV @ $T = -30^\circ C$ \label{subfig-1:3d-iv_frigo}]{%
   \input{./cap4/3d/iv_frigo}
}
\subfloat[Misura a 50V @ $T = -30^\circ C$ \label{subfig-2:strip_cv}]{%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{./3d/misure/50V_frigo}
  \put(-40,-7){\footnotesize elettroni}
}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{Frigo}
\label{fig:frigo}
\end{figure}
```

[image: subfig]

Comment: related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378084/how-to-adjust-the-position-of-subfloat/ (actually duplicate).

Comment: And btw: Avoid using `subfig` if you do not have to use it.  There's the more flexible `subcaption` out there.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me. Using package `subcaption`.

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a.pdf}
        \caption{Caption for figure 1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a.pdf}
        \caption{Caption for figure 2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \vspace{6pt}
    \caption{Caption for the two figures}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `subfloatrow` environment, from `floatrow`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}%[demo]
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\floatsetup{capposition=below, floatrowsep=qquad}
\centering
\ffigbox{%
\begin{subfloatrow}
\centering
    \ffigbox[0.40\textwidth]{\caption{\emph{Traccia Table} (1939)}}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{traccia-table}%[width=0.4\textwidth]
  }
    \ffigbox[0.50\textwidth]{\caption{\emph{Le Cahier d’une Écolière} (1931)}}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{cahier}%
  }
\end{subfloatrow}}%
{\caption{Méret Oppenheim (1913-1985)} \label{MO}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]